# ubuntu 10.04 mount issues every time I reboot

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

Basically, every time I boot, I can't mount to /dev/shm, so I manually create the directory and reboot. I can get into ubuntu fine, but then when I reboot one more time, it runs into the same problem. Basically, I think /dev/shm gets deleted automatically. Is there a solution to this? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

We need way more information.. what OS/version are you running?  Is it a VM?  If so which hypervisor etc etc..

Give us the output of `cat /etc/mtab` and `cat /etc/fstab` when it works and when failing.  If the directory isn't there and you type `mount /dev/shm` what happens?  After a reboot where the directory gets deleted what do you see in `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/syslog`

Note: Use sudo if needed